# How to use polymorphism on return type of grpc code first service?

Tags: c#, grpc, .net-6.0, grpc-dotnet, grpc-code-first

I want to use polymorphic return type in grpc service with code first approach, but I do not know how to do it?

I have service contract like below

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IGreeterService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        BaseResponse SayHello(HelloRequest request,
            CallContext context = default);
    }
```

And I have two derived response like below

```
public class ResponseA : BaseResponse
{
string foo;
}

public class ResponseB: BaseResponse
{
string bar;
}
```

my `BaseResponse` exist in another library, and I do not want (and I can not) to change this library.

```
public abstract class BaseResponse
{
public string hoo;
}
```

So finally I want to implement `SayHello` like below

```
public class GreeterService : IGreeterService
{

  public BaseResponse SayHello(HelloRequest request, CallContext context = default)
  {
    if (request.Name == "Heelo")
    {
      return new ResponseA() {foo = "Hi", hoo = "Hey"};
    }
    else
      return new ResponseB() {bar = "bye", hoo = "You"};
  }
}
```

But I do not know how can I say to `OperationContract` that I have two type for return type?

Comment: I add some sample for this code, to see problem https://github.com/BSVN/Commons/pull/68

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't alter `BaseResponse`, you will have to configure it manually - for example:

```cs
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(BaseResponse), false)
    // fields of BaseResponse
    .Add(1, nameof(BaseResponse.hoo))
    // sub-types of BaseResponse
    .AddSubType(10, typeof(ResponseA))
    .AddSubType(11, typeof(ResponseB));
```

Here I'm assuming that `ResponseA` and `ResponseB` can at least be altered, i.e.

```cs
[ProtoContract]
public class ResponseA : BaseResponse
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string foo;
}
```

If that *isn't* possible, you'll also need to configure *them* manually, for example:

```cs
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(ResponseA), false)
    .Add(1, nameof(ResponseA.foo));
```

Comment: Where is RuntimeTypeModel? and How to access them? and when configure this? before DI?

Comment: that's from protobuf-net; you need `using ProtoBuf.Meta;` - and yes, this should be very early in the app

Comment: Thats great, so I have question, if gRPC have some fantastic facility, why you do not create some attribute to add derived class to base class, from derived class instead of base class? it is very better approach, for decoupling base class from derived class.

Comment: How to use `interface` instead of BaseResponse?

Comment: @sorosh_sabz that doesn't work well; I suggest: "don't"